# Why BufferedOutputStream doesn't output data?

Tags: java

I try to create my own class to output system out stream to console and to the file at the same time using BufferedStream. But data doesn't appear from the BufferedOutputStream. How should I fix this problem?

```
package com.library.stream;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class DoubleEndedStream {
InputStream theInput;
OutputStream theOutput;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException {
    DoubleEndedStream sr = new DoubleEndedStream(System.in, System.out);
    sr.doublingTheStream();
}

public DoubleEndedStream(InputStream in, OutputStream out) {
    theInput = in;
    theOutput = out;    
}

public void doublingTheStream() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException  {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\log.txt");
        BufferedOutputStream bout1 = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
        BufferedOutputStream bout2 = new BufferedOutputStream(theOutput);
        try {
            while (true) {
                int datum = theInput.read();
                if (datum == -1) break;
                bout1.write(datum);
                bout2.write(datum);
            }
            bout1.flush();
            bout2.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't read from System.in!");
        }

        bout1.close();
        bout2.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't find log.txt");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Are you having problems with the BufferedOutputStrem to console, to file or to both?

Comment: Is it throwing exception? I think if (datum == -1) break; this part executes when program starts as there may be no data and loop is broken.

Comment: You'll need to flush your stream. It's filling up its buffer before it writes.

Comment: I had a problem with both. It doesn't throw the exception. Thanks everyone. I think Binyamin Sharet has given right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `theInput` is `System.in`, as long as you don't close it, (`ctrl-d` in unix), it will not return `-1`, but hang and wait for input. Since you perform `flush()` only when received `-1`, you never get to this point. Try flushing after the `write()` instead.

Comment: But if i would flushing everytime i write the advantages of BufferedStream will be droped

Comment: So flush every 3rd, or 5th, or whatever you think that fits.